# getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag unpredictable behaviour

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

If I'm adding fragments to my activity like this:

```
    fragment_tags = new ArrayList<String>();
    fragment_tags.add("user_fragment");
    fragment_tags.add("memorial_fragment");

    UserFragment user = new UserFragment();
    MemorialFragment memorial = new MemorialFragment();

    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, user, fragment_tags.get(0));
    ft.add(R.id.content_frame, memorial, fragment_tags.get(1));
    ft.commit();
```

and then after some time I'm trying to retrieve these fragments like this:

```
    List<Fragment> frg = getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments();
    Fragment fragUser = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
            "user_fragment");
    Fragment fragUserID = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.user_fragment_id);
            Log.d("MV", "fragments size:" + (frg == null ? " null" : frg.size()));
```

Log.d will always return size of 2, but fragUser is sometimes null and sometimes it's the fragment I put in transaction.

Which is more interesting is that this code:

```
    try {
        Log.d("MV", "0:" + frg.get(0).toString());
        Log.d("MV", "1:" + frg.get(1).toString());
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        Log.d("MV", "null caught");
    }
```

will sometimes work for both fragments and sometimes just for the first and if i do smething like this:

```
if(frg.get(0) == fragUser)
```

it will be sometimes evaluated as true, but not often.. I don't really understand this behaviour, but I need to implement switching between multiple fragments, so I need to get reference to exact fragment. Anybody? I'm trying to solve this for 6 hours now and I really dont understand how to do this. Thank you

Comment: Well to answer one part... **"if(frg.get(0) == fragUser)"** ...you can't compare objects using `==`. You need to use `if(frg.get(0).equals(fragUser))`

Comment: Squonk actually this is my intention.. I don't care if objects have the same attributes, but if their references are the same, they must be the same objects.. I want the same fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was posted by me back in 2013, gained over 1000 views but is still without any response, I will try to sum up what I've learned over the years when working with fragments.

1. Don't use getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() (more on this in [getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() shows a compile time error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42572249/getsupportfragmentmanager-getfragments-shows-a-compile-time-error))
2. FragmentManager is there to manage fragments lifecycle. Don't try to put fragments into your own lists or keep strong reference to them
3. The reason why the `if(frg.get(0) == fragUser)` didn't work consistently is tied to the point 2. - FragmentManager manages the fragments, so when it decides to kill one and recreate it again, the references will not match.

Now the question - how to safely work with fragments?

1. Pass data to fragments in a bundle using setArguments() method, so Android can kill&recreate the fragment.
2. `FragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.some_id)` will find fragment that is attached to the view with id some_id. It is very likely that if you have multiple fragments added to R.id.some_id, `FragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.some_id)` will give different results (but it's usually a very good method to find out which fragment is currently visible unless you also hide/display your fragments)
3. Understand different methods from FragmentTransaction API, especially differences between `add` and `replace`, `hide`, `detach`, `remove` and `show`.
4. Sometimes things just don't work (crashes when multiple fragment transition animations run at once) or your app is not a good use case for fragments. You can read more about the latter in now classic post https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/advocating-against-android-fragments-81fd0b462c97