# getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() shows a compile time error

Tags: java, android, compiler-errors

Calling `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()` shows a compile time error with the message below:

> getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments() can only be called from
>   within the same library group(groupId = com.android.support)

I have imported the following classes in `MainActivity`:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

`MainActivity` extends `AppCompatActivity`.

My project module level `build.gradle` file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.floatingdemo"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

This is the source code for the method `getFragments` inside `FragmentManager.java`.

```
/**
 * Get a list of all fragments that have been added to the fragment manager.
 *
 * @return The list of all fragments or null if none.
 * @hide
 */
@RestrictTo(LIBRARY_GROUP)
public abstract List<Fragment> getFragments();
```

I have recently updated my Android Studio to the latest stable version (2.3) and updated the Android Gradle plugin as well. I think this may be relevant because I have not previously seen this error.

Comment: pls post the code where you use `getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()`

Comment: instead of getSupportFragmentManager try getFragmentManager because in your import statement fragment manager is there. Give it a try

Comment: @NiteshMishra, that is `SupportFragmentManager` only as you can see it is from support library v4. `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As noticeable in the [`FragmentManager` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.html), `getFragments()` is not a public method available to apps, but an internal implementation detail of the Support Library, hence the use of the [`RestrictTo` annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RestrictTo.html) that was added to prevent usage of private APIs.

You'll want to change your code to not use `getFragments` and only use the public APIs.

Comment: Yeah, but what could be the reason behind this restriction?

Comment: Since `getFragments()` is now restricted, what is the "public API' for getting a list of all `Fragments` currently added to the `FragmentManager`?

Comment: @jenzz - there's no API for that. You could certainly register a [FragmentLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks.html) and keep your own list.

Comment: this makes little sense. hasn't this been working so far?

Comment: @CptEric - it has always been a private API.

Comment: @ianhanniballake what if we still use this private method? As it's running properly even though it's showing compile time error. Are there any cons of using it?

Comment: @indramurari my assumption would be that the method will eventually become entirely inaccessible eventually. I would go ahead and implement your own methods to do this right now just to be safe.

Comment: Why on Earth is `FragmentLifecycleCallbacks` abstract and not an interface?

Comment: @ianhanniballake In my project I dont see FragmentLifecycleCallbacks at all under android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager. Any idea why this might be the case?

Comment: @Kalinga - make sure you are using [25.2.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-2-0) or higher

Comment: While the non-support FragmentManager API seems to have the method as private, the `android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager` method is still public and appears to be part of the public API but I am also receiving the same error as OP (and experiencing the same behaviour). Could this perhaps be a bug?

Comment: I use it like this:         for (Fragment fragment : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        } and got a npe which says the fragment is null. I don't know why.

Answer (score 6):

Alternative For those who may be using `getFragments()` in their coding, I have replaced my code to get last fragment in `backstack` to this code(I am using this code in `onBackPressed()` to apply changes according to `currentFragment` assumed all fragments are added to backstack):

```
FragmentManager.BackStackEntry backStackEntryAt = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1);
currentFragment = backStackEntryAt.getName();
```

Comment: If you have a viewpager, `getBackStackEntryCount()` will be empty or without count of thowse fragments.

Answer (score 3):

You can use （make sure using [25.2.0](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html#25-2-0) or higher ）

```
supportFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(object : FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
    override fun onFragmentAttached(fm: FragmentManager?, f: Fragment?, context: Context?) {
        f?.let { fList.add(it) }
    }

    override fun onFragmentDetached(fm: FragmentManager?, f: Fragment?) {
        f?.let { fList.remove(it) }
    }

}, false)
```

Instead of using `getFragments()`